# Extra parameter is getting added in url in axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I'm facing problem while posting data using axios, first time data is getting saved in database properly. But second time, url is taking last id.

ex : first time url will be like : www.ex.com/images
second time : www.ex.com/images?details_id=1

```
export let url = axios.create({
    baseURL: constants.URL,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    responseType: 'json',
});


const data = new FormData();
data.append("image", props.image);
data.append("details_id", props.details_id);

config.auth.post('images', data)
    .then(function (response) {
     //my code
}))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like the problem is in the code you provided.

```
data.append("image", props.image);
data.append("details_id", props.details_id);

config.auth.post('images', data)
    .then(function (response) {
     //my code
}))
```

Here you are passing the details_id with the request so if you don't want it than remove that part.